# Shared OpenGL context and glBufferData

Tags: c++, opengl

I had the following plan for implementing an asynchronous buffer upload in an OpenGL program:

- Create shared contextes. Render thread has one, worker thread has one.
- Worker thread calls glBufferData. Each call allocates and uploads data completely fresh.
- Render thread probes buffer upload state using fences. Once finished, it starts using the buffer for drawing.

My question now is: Will the `glBufferData` in the worker thread affect the performance of the main render thread in some way? Like will a flush/finish in the main render thread cause the buffer upload be triggered synchronously and stall the overall pipeline even if the render thread does not use it for drawing?